# MacOS 11 or later required! error on PyCharm

Tags: python, macos

I am learning how to use python by watching some online videos.  When I run the code below using PyCharm, I get the following:

macOS 11 or later required!

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

I have an M1 Mac mini with macOS Big Sur 11.1.  This was happening when I had Python 3.8.2.  Then, I installed Python 3.9.1.  I keep getting the same error. How can I fix this?

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()

print(bob)
```

Comment: Hello, do you also have a detailed output of the error, paste it in your question.

Comment: Try to downgrade from 3.9 to 3.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used Homebrew to do your Python installation, there have been some reported issues with Python3 installs via brew ([Source 1](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/3722), [Source 2](https://bugs.python.org/issue42480)). Updates are always in the works though, so you could try remedying your problem first with a brew update. If the issue persists, the current recommendation is to actually install Python directly from their site ([Similar issue with fix reported](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/3722#issuecomment-749304857)).

In conclusion, if using brew, try a brew update first, if that doesn't fix your issue, install Python directly!

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Comment: I have the same issue with python 3.8.0. The problem is I need to use pyenv, and it is not possible to add a version downloaded from the site with pyenv.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to do a simple `brew update && brew upgrade`, but that did not help much.

When doing my research, it appears Apple supplies an old version of tcl-tk (8.5.xx) which causes the issue.
Just installing a newer tcl-tk using brew solved the issue:

```
brew install tcl-tk
```

This should install tcl-tk 8.6.xx (it's 8.6.11 at the time of writing).

The simplest verification is:

```
% python3
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan  8 2021, 17:17:43)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter as t
>>> t._test()
```

A test small GUI window should come up.

Comment: `brew update && brew upgrade` did the trick for me after I ran `brew install tcl-tk` things still were not working until the upgrade and update.

Comment: For me it did not help

Comment: @János, please be more specific if you want help. Unfortunately, the information you provided is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

After having tried the above and still not getting my project to work, I've created a new project and set the base interpreter to

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

instead of leaving the preset one which was `/usr/bin/python3`

Worked like a (Py)Charm (Sorry for that. I'll show myself out)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all solutions without any result. After all I changed environment from `VirtualEnv` to [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and set it in new PyCharm project.

Now it works well.

[image: PyCharm project setup]