# Unable to run Turtle in python on Mac OS V.S. Code

Tags: python

I have written the following code in V.S. Code on Mac:-

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()

bob.forward(100)

turtle.done()
```

But, whenever I execute the code the following error occurs:-

```
macOS 11 or later required !
Abort trap: 6
```

Would appreciate it if anyone could please help me to resolve this issue! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You should have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452383/macos-11-or-later-required-error-on-pycharm) post.

Comment: @JulienRipoche I tried the solution but, it didn't worked for me(: