# How to install Python to not get "macOS 11 or later required !" error?

Tags: python, macos

I have a Mac with the most recent OS 11.1 Big Sur, and Python 3.9. I did like here they suggest:

```
brew install tcl-tk
brew update && upgrade
```

[MacOS 11 or later required! error on PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452383/macos-11-or-later-required-error-on-pycharm)

But it did not help.

I try use `seedrecover.py`, form here: https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover

```
python3 seedrecover.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install pycharm, or python directly? If you just download it from python.org (https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/), then run the installer, it will remove any previous installations of the same version, and give you an option to replace all other versions. Then go to the terminal and run `python3 -v` and see if you get an error. If you do, add it to your system path. If you are getting a version error, make sure you've updated homebrew, or if installing from the website, downloaded the right version.

Comment: And what error did you get when running `python3 seedrecover.py`?

Comment: got this: macOS 11 or later required !